# code is faster on single cpu but very slow on multiple processes why?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, joblib

I have some code to sort some values originally in sparse matrix and zip it together with another data. I used some kind of optimizations to make it fast and the code is 20x faster than it was as it is below:

This code takes 8s on single CPU core:

```
 # cosine_sim is a sparse csr matrix
 # names is an numpy array of length 400k

 cosine_sim_labeled = []
 for i in range(0, cosine_sim.shape[0]):
     row = cosine_sim.getrow(i).toarray()[0]
     non_zero_sim_indexes = np.nonzero(row)
     non_zero_sim_values = row[non_zero_sim_indexes]
     non_zero_sim_values = [round(freq, 4) for freq in non_zero_sim_values]
     non_zero_names_values = np.take(names, non_zero_sim_indexes)[0]
     zipped = zip(non_zero_names_values, non_zero_sim_values)
     cosine_sim_labeled.append(sorted(zipped, key=lambda cv: -cv[1])[1:][:top_similar_count])
```

But if I use same code with multi core (to make it even faster) it takes 300 seconds:

```
#split is array of arrays of numbers like [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] it is meant to generate batches of array indexes to be processed with each paralel process
split = np.array_split(range(0, cosine_sim.shape[0]), cosine_sim.shape[0] / batch)

def sort_rows(split):
 cosine_sim_labeled = []
 for i in split:
     row = cosine_sim.getrow(i).toarray()[0]
     non_zero_sim_indexes = np.nonzero(row)
     non_zero_sim_values = row[non_zero_sim_indexes]
     non_zero_sim_values = [round(freq, 4) for freq in non_zero_sim_values]
     non_zero_names_values = np.take(names, non_zero_sim_indexes)[0]
     zipped = zip(non_zero_names_values, non_zero_sim_values)
     cosine_sim_labeled.append(sorted(zipped, key=lambda cv: -cv[1])[1:][:top_similar_count])
return cosine_sim_labeled

# this ensures paralel CPU execution
rows = Parallel(n_jobs=CPU_use, verbose=40)(delayed(sort_rows)(x) for x in split)
cosine_sim_labeled = np.vstack(rows).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

you do realize that your new parallel function `sort_rows` does not even use the `split` argument? all it does is to distribute all the data to all processes, which takes time, then each process is doing the exact same calculation, only to return the whole data back to the main process, which again takes time

Comment: ah good catch! you are right, i will change the question. it is good at me but i posted it wrong here